Non-reduced loci of the flat limit of a family of projective varieties
When reading Hartshorne Example III.$9.8.4$, I have some trouble determining the non-reduced loci of the flat limit of a family of varieties. The construction of this limit is explained below.
Let $X_1$ be a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}_k$ not containing the point $P=[0:\cdots:0:1]$ and let $\varphi\colon \mathbb{P}^{n+1}_k\to \mathbb{P}^{n}_k $ be the linear projection away from the point $P$.
The flat family $X_t$ parametrized by $\mathbb{A}^1_k$, which has the property that $X_0$ is a scheme having the same underlying topological space as $\varphi(X_1)$ and that all other members $X_t,t\neq 0,$ are isomorphic to $X_1$, is constructed as follows: for each $a\in k$ non-zero, consider the automorphism $\sigma_a$ of $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}_k$ given by $[x_0:\cdots:x_{n+1}]\mapsto [x_0:\cdots:ax_{n+1}] $;
then $X_a= \sigma_a(X_1)$ is a flat family over $\mathbb{A}^1_k-\{0\}$ so Proposition III.$9.8$ implies that it extends to a unique flat family $X_t$ defined over all of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$.
In Example III.$9.8.3$ and Exercise III.$9.2$, we considered the cases when $X_1$ is a twisted cubic curve in $\mathbb{P}^3_k$ and the linear projection maps $X_1$ to a nodal plane cubic or a cuspidal plane cubic. In both cases the flat limit $X_0$ is a non-reduced curve whose non-reduced loci is exactly the embedded point supported at the unique singular point of the image $\varphi(X_1)$.
Now back to general closed subschemes $X_1\subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}_k$.
Question:

Is it true that the non-reduced loci is a proper closed subset of $X_0$? If not, what are the assumptions needed to make this true?
Is there a bound on the number of embedded components of $X_0$?

Partial answers are welcomed. Listing references discussing the reducedness of schemes in general will also be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Regarding (2): let $X_1 = \left{x_1,...,x_k,y_1,...,y_k\right}$ be a collection of $2k$ reduced points. Take a limit as $x_i \to y_i$. Then $X_0$ is a union of $k$ double points. I'm far from an expert on such matters, but my understanding is now that each double point (or its support?) is an embedded component, and $k$ was arbitrary. If you want a connected example, I think you can argue similarly with two chains of lines $L_1\cup L_2\cup\cdots\cup L_k$ and $L_1'\cup L_2'\cup\cdots\cup L_k'$ and let each $L_i$ approach $L_i'$ (with intersection points taken to intersection points etc.)...

...and if you want an example with $X_1$ smooth, I believe you can always smooth a chain of lines in projective space to a rational space curve and then specialize that to $X_0 = L_1'\cup\cdots\cup L_k'$.

@TabesBridges Thanks for the comment! Your example almost answered my first question as in that case the non-reduced loci is all of $X_0$. The context of my question is that I want to show that a linear projection does not change the degree of a nonsingular curve. By a Hilbert polynomial argument, this is equivalent to the ideal sheaf of nilpotents of $X_0$ being supported at finitely many closed points, i.e. the embedded points, so the number of embedded points is the increment in arithmetic genus under the projection. I'd also appreciate any input on showing the preservation of degree.
